# how to do Boolean grouping search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grouping, boolean-logic, boolean-search

How to do Boolean grouping search in ruby on rails with dynamic values?
Can anyone give me sample example or reference link for Boolean grouping search.

Example:

```
(quick OR brown) AND fox
```

quick OR brown should be executed first and that result should do AND search with fox.

Thanks.

Comment: Tip: you can use SQL in queries.

Comment: @llya can u give me one example or reference link?

Comment: `YourModel.where('(field1 = quick OR field2 = brown) AND field3 = fox')`